# Delete protected registry key with a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Trying to delete the following registry key with a batch file but I can't even delete in the registry editor.  Any ideas on how to write a batch file to do it, maybe it need to change permission also.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM\

There are about 8 sub keys under PRINTENUM such as {1974F44D-A278-......} that I want to be deleted.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM

Same as above.

Comment: "Trying to" implies that you've made an effort already, but you forgot to include it. It helps when you're asking us to diagnose a problem with code if you actually show us your code. StackOverflow isn't a site for "Here's my requirement. Can you write the code for me? Be back later to pick it up. Thanks!" type questions. :-) Access to HKLM for anything other than read access requires administrator rights under modern versions of Windows. Are you running in a command prompt you've opened as an administrator?

Comment: That information does not help, because it's an incomplete sentence that says nothing. Please  [edit] your question to be more specific about what "Trying to" means, what **specifically** you have tried, and whether the account you're using (and the command window from which the batch file is being run) have administrative rights.

Comment: Basically it just a "remove printers.reg" file on the \\server\scripts\  containing [-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM\{1974F44D-A278-470C-AF90-2B94CC6F71A0}] etc and I have a batch file called remove reg.bat that contains %systemroot%\regedit.exe /s "\\server\scripts\remove printers.reg" The registry won't remove even if I am in registry editor and delete it, it says cannot delete, error while deleting key.

Answer (score 3):

I did try psexec -s -i on the server and having the .reg file on the server too, but just couldn't run it on the client with admin command prompt using \server..... tried all sorts of reg import, to running the reg file with -aaceptuela given me error 0 which should be no errors and error 1 which I tried to login using -u  to run it or runas etc.,.,

At the end I had to copy the .reg file and psexec to the local hard drive with the script and ran D:\PsExec.exe -i -s -accepteula reg import "D:\hidden_printers.reg" for it to work.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

First, read the Microsoft support article [What are Control Sets? What is CurrentControlSet?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100010).

After doing that it should be clear that whatever is modified under `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet` is in real done (usually) also on `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet001` and applied on next boot also to `HKLM\SYSTEM\ControlSet002`.

Key `HKLM\SYSTEM\Select` contains the information which control set is the current control set (usually control set 1), which one is the default control set on Windows boot (also usually control set 1) and which one is the last known good (usally control set 2).

Next read the Microsoft developer network article about [HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum Registry Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546173.aspx).

By default only the SYSTEM account has the necessary permissions to change something in enum registry tree. That can be changed with `Regedit.exe`, but it is not advisable to do that. Enumerator keys are removed automatically on uninstalling a device with it's driver for example with the Windows device manager. It is not advisable to delete them manually from Windows registry.

It is possible to navigate in `Regedit.exe` to key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM`, right click on this key, left click on context menu item **Permissions**, enable full access for group everyone, close the permissions dialog, delete the subkeys, re-open the permissions dialog for the key `PRINTENUM` again and uncheck full access for everyone to restore the standard permissions. But again, don't do that except you really know what you do.

See super user question [Change registry permissions via command line (batch file)](https://superuser.com/questions/712392/change-registry-permissions-via-command-line-batch-file) containing the answer on your question.